# Printing all rows of a SQLite database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

For debugging/checkpointing purposes, I wanted to print out all rows of a SQLite database in Android. I did not find anything that answered this precise question: **How can I easily print out all rows of a SQLite database in a human-readable format?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution I came up with looks like this:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String TAG = "DbHelper";
    ... // functions omitted


    /**
     * Helper function that parses a given table into a string
     * and returns it for easy printing. The string consists of 
     * the table name and then each row is iterated through with
     * column_name: value pairs printed out.
     *
     * @param db the database to get the table from
     * @param tableName the the name of the table to parse
     * @return the table tableName as a string
     */
    public String getTableAsString(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getTableAsString called");
        String tableString = String.format("Table %s:\n", tableName);
        Cursor allRows  = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
        if (allRows.moveToFirst() ){
            String[] columnNames = allRows.getColumnNames();
            do {
                for (String name: columnNames) {
                    tableString += String.format("%s: %s\n", name,
                            allRows.getString(allRows.getColumnIndex(name)));
                }
                tableString += "\n";

            } while (allRows.moveToNext());
        }

        return tableString;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps some of you.

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor.

Comment: Your method is great but I wish i could return all the columns separately in two strings. (i have 2. one email and one password).

Comment: Including the imports would be nice

Answer (score 3):

I changed it a bit: separated the Cursor toString (can be used independently), designed as a Table print.

```
public String tableToString(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    Log.d("","tableToString called");
    String tableString = String.format("Table %s:\n", tableName);
    Cursor allRows  = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
    tableString += cursorToString(allRows);
    return tableString;
}

public String cursorToString(Cursor cursor){
    String cursorString = "";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() ){
        String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
        for (String name: columnNames) 
            cursorString += String.format("%s ][ ", name);
        cursorString += "\n";
        do {
            for (String name: columnNames) {
                cursorString += String.format("%s ][ ",
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name)));
            }
            cursorString += "\n";
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return cursorString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another quicker option would be to use a rooted device and then export the app database to your development machine to be opened with a desktop app capable of reading sqlite dbs. There is also an app on Google play called sqlite debugger which you can use to view app databases but this again requires root.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I can see use-cases where that  would be a better approach.

Comment: You dont need a rooted device to download db to the development PC.

Comment: @RalphMclee care to elaborate?